# Copy Only Cells From Visible Sheets And Paste Into Next Free Column VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that is currently running where it is coping cell (C2: C3) from all sheets and is pasting in the "Master" sheet. The issue that I have is that I want it to only copy the visible sheets as some of my hidden sheets have different data running my sheets. I also have an issue of it pasting in the next row and I want it to paste in the next column and can't figure it out :/.

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim LRowO As Long, LRowI As Long
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
For Each wsInput In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wsInput.Name <> wsOutput.Name Then
        With wsInput
            Set rng = .Range("C2:C3")
            rng.Copy
            With wsOutput
                LRowO = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & LRowO).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next wsInput

Exit Sub

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to check if the worksheet is hidden and also keep track of what the next column would be and increment it each time you paste into it. Here is your code modified for both of those things

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
LRowI As Long
Dim nextCol as Long
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
nextCol = 1
For Each wsInput In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wsInput.Name <> wsOutput.Name and wsInput.Visible = True Then
        With wsInput
            Set rng = .Range("C2:C3")
            rng.Copy
            With wsOutput
                .Cells(1, nextCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                nextCol = nextCol + 1
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next wsInput

Exit Sub

 End Sub
```

Comment: that looks to be more of what I am looking for however I am still seeing an error with the:
     nextCol = 1 

in that I am seeing a Variable not defined Compile error :/.

Comment: Oh, try dimensioning it up above with the others. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Awesome. It is now pasting it into the Master sheet but it is pasting the next answer one column over as well as one row below the last. I was trying to get them to paste directly next to the one before. Would I just delete the +1?

Comment: `PasteSpecial` may need a range object, so maybe try `.Range(.Cells(1, nextCol), .Cells(lRowO, nextCol).PastSpecial ...`

Comment: OK. I guess I was confused. I thought you wanted it to be one column over  each time.

Comment: Are you saying you just want to paste one column over, but not one row down?

Comment: Correct. One column over but not one row down. Sorry for any confusion! It appears to be pasting into the correct column but the 2nd and 3rd paste are still happening a row below the first after the +1 to the row has been removed..

Comment: Then does `.Cells(1, nextCol).PasteSpecial...` work?

Comment: That did it. Thanks Matt!!

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. I've certainly profited plenty from this site.

Answer (score 1):

Check the

```
worksheets(wsInput).visible
```

property. For example, change

```
If wsInput.Name<>wsOutput.name Then
```

to

```
If wsInput.Name<>wsOutput.name and worksheets(wsInput).visible Then
```

This will only use worksheets that are visible.

More information located here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx

I don't think I fully understand the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this to check if your sheets are visible/hidden.

```
If wsInput.Visible = True Then
        ' Do copy here
```

or

```
If Sheets(wsInput.Name).Visible = True Then
        ' Do copy here
```

Then for pasting into the next column over, you can use the offset property.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset, columnOffset).Activate
```

Changing `rowOffset` and `columnOffset` to the numbers needed to get to the cell directly one column to the right. i.e.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
```

Will change the current selection from `A1` to `B1`